# React props is undefined - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a little stumped with this one and I'm starting to suspect it's something and my eyes are just glazing over it. I'm initializing `this.state` with `ingredients: []` and then passing it as a prop to a child component `<RecipePreview ingredients={this.state.ingredients} instructions={this.state.instructions}/>`. In the child component I have the following `this.props.ingredients.map` which throws the following error:

> myRecipes-d3093398f8879b688ddb.js:41689 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'map' of undefined

Everything seems set up correctly so I'm not sure where the mistake lies. One thing to note is when I remove the map and simply render the contents of the prop (say [1,2,3]) it renders without error.

Below are the two components. There are more components in this file but I'm only pasting the two relevant ones. Let me know what you guys think.

```
class CreateRecipe extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            ingredients: [[1,2,3]],
            instructions: [[]]
        };

        this.addIngredient = this.addIngredient.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    addIngredient(quantity, unit, ingredient) {
        let ingredients = this.state.ingredients;
        ingredients.push([quantity, unit, ingredient]);
        this.setState({ingredients: ingredients})
    };

    handleSubmit = event => {

    };

    validateForm() {
        return this.state.ingredients !== [] || this.state.instructions !== [];
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className={"list-container flex-row"}>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <AddIngredient addIngredient={this.addIngredient}/>
                    <Button block bsSize="small" disabled={!this.validateForm()} type="submit">
                        Add Recipe
                    </Button>
                </form>
                <RecipePreview ingredients={this.state.ingredients} instructions={this.state.instructions}/>
            </div>)
    }
}

class RecipePreview extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Recipe Preview
                {this.props.ingredients.map((ingredient, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={`ingredient${index}`}>
                            {`${ingredient[0]} ${ingredient[1]} ${ingredient[2]}`}
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, `this.state.ingredients !== []` is always true because two arrays are never equal to each other. `console.log([] === [])`.

Comment: Thanks. I will switch it to `this.state.ingredients.length === 0`

Comment: does the error occur immedialty, or only after you've clicked `<AddIngredient />`?

Comment: Check out the resolution above! I knew it was something stupid. Your comment earlier made me recheck my other components.

Comment: You should post your "resolution" as an answer below instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're trying to call the `map` method on something that's undefined. One solution might be to check whether the array exists before mapping the array:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Recipe Preview
                {this.props && this.props.ingredients && this.props.ingredients.map((ingredient, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={`ingredient${index}`}>
                            {`${ingredient[0]} ${ingredient[1]} ${ingredient[2]}`}
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

RESOLUTION

A comment below made me scan over my components one more time. I found that I had a duplicate `<RecipePreview/>` in another component. The fact that one got rendered without me passing in a prop was the issue.

```
class ListContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"list-container flex-row"}>
                <MyRecipesList setRecipeAsSelected={this.props.setRecipeAsSelected}
                               selectedRecipe={this.props.selectedRecipe} recipeOwner={this.props.recipeOwner}/>
                <CreateRecipe selectedRecipe={this.props.selectedRecipe}/>
                <RecipePreview/>
                <Instructions/>
                {/*<Advertisements/>*/}
            </div>)
    }
}
```